# Grid Modify Plugin Redmine Equivalent

Tags: redmine, trac

I'm trying to look into whether or not there is a Grid Modify equivalent plugin that is available for Redmine. We are currently using Trac and were wondering if we can have similar functionality of quickly edit/modify fields in mutiple tickets on Issues page.

Comment: Without any plugin, in Redmine, you can select several issues and modify them by doing a right click on one of them. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm talking more in line like how you can allow dropdowns in the Issues report for any custom field column and being able to select value from the dropdown and change the value for that field in the Issue on the fly

Comment: See http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GridModifyPlugin for an example of what Trac's Grid Modify Plugin can do